# testdisk undelete not showing up for exFAT formatted partition

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk, exfat

I have a microSD card used as external storage on my Android phone and I accidentally deleted a file on it. The partition on which this file resided is formatted with the exFAT filesystem.

Now I am trying to recover it on my PC with [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) following the [undelete file for FAT guide](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT). However when I enter the [Advanced] menu, my partition is showing up as "Linux" and the [Undelete] option is missing.

I tried changing the type to 0x07 (HPFS - NTFS) via the [Type] menu (this was the type most closely related to exFAT that I could find), which makes the [Undelete] option visible, but shows "Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged." upon selection.

Now what can I do to make the partition being recognized as exFAT to undelete my file? I could not find anything regarding my issue on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Analyze] instead of the [Advanced] tab and do a quick search. Now the partition should show up correctly and you can press <kbd>p</kbd> to browse the files on the card. There you should also see your deleted files and be able to copy the file in question by pressing <kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: If the solution worked, then please accept the answer, even if it is your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for remembering me, when I created the answer it said I have to wait two days before I can accept it and then this got lost somewhere in my mind :P